# Problems in understanding a step from a proof of the Radon-Nikodym theorem

Tags: measure-theory, radon-nikodym

From page 115 of "Measure theory and probability theory" by Krishna and Soumendra, as a step of the Radon-Nikodym theorem's proof:

> Suppose that $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are finite measures. Let $\mu$ be
> the measure $\mu = \mu_1 + \mu_2$ and let $H = L^2(\mu)$. Define a linear function T on
> H by
> \begin{gather*} 
> T(f)=\int f d\mu_1
> \end{gather*}

I don't get how $T$ can be well-defined on $L^2(\mu)$. Infact we have that $f \in L^2(\mu)$ implies:

\begin{gather*} 
\int  f^2  d\mu =  \int  f^2  d\mu_1  + \int  f^2  d\mu_2  < \infty
\end{gather*}

That means  $f \in L^2(\mu_1 )$ but  not necessarely that $f$ is integrable. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int | f|d\mu_1 \leq \sqrt {\int f^{2} d\mu_1} \sqrt {\mu_1(\Omega)}$ by Holder's inequality.

Comment: This assumes that both measures are finite.

Comment: @Crostul It is clearly stated that both are finite measures.

Comment: Did you mean $\int | f|d\mu_1 \leq \left( \int f^{2} d\mu_1 \right)^{1/2} \mu_1(\Omega)$, Holder's inequality with $p=2$ and $q=1$? However the approach is clear, thank you.

Comment: @GiovanniBarbarani You write $|f|$ as the product of $|f|$ and $1$ and apply Holder's inequality. $\sqrt {\int 1^{2} d\mu_1}=\sqrt {\mu_1(\Omega)}$.

Comment: You're right.I miscasculated $q$, sorry.